# Flutter: How to declare HashMap of StreamSubscription

Tags: flutter, hashmap

I have declared hash map for subscriptions, like this:

```
HashMap<String, StreamSubscription<Event>> = subscriptions
```

But when i am filling values, it show for me, that types doesn't match. Error tells that `Argument of type StreamSubscription<Event> can't be assigned to parameter of type StreamSubscription<Event> Function()`. 
When i am creating dirrectly variable like this:

```
StreamSubscription<Event> e = subscription.eventStream.listen((event) {
  print(event.arguments[0]);
});
```

It shows that type is correct. 
So how should i declare hashmap of `HashMap<String, StreamSubscription<Event>>`, if

```
_subscriptions.putIfAbsent(uri, e);
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `ifAbsent` is not a value - it is a function returning value - more: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html - the docs say: *"Look up the value of key, or add a new value if it isn't there.

Returns the value associated to key, if there is one. Otherwise calls ifAbsent to get a new value, associates key to that value, and then returns the new value."*

Comment: Ok thanks. My mistake